# Convert certain columns of csv into dictionary of sums

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, bigdata

I have a big csv file that I got from this website : https://data.baltimorecity.gov/Public-Safety/BPD-Part-1-Victim-Based-Crime-Data/wsfq-mvij.

The file contains information of the crimes that happened in Baltimore. 
I need a function that reads all the CrimeDate dates, and adds up the Total Incidents in each date, so that I can get a dictionary like this, for example:

```
[{CrimeDate: 05/14/2016, Total Incidents: 50}, {CrimeDate: 05/13/2016, Total Incidents: 67}.........]
```

Note that the Total Incidents is a random number I picked just to use it as an example.

The output needs to have the date, and the total number of incidents for each date.
I know how to convert a csv file to a dictionary, but since this file is very big it takes very long time to read, so I only want to read the fields I need.

Comment: You could load the CSV into pandas dataframe and remove the columns you don't need

Comment: I cannot change the CSV file, it must remain intact.

Comment: Not what I said. You keep your CSV, but load it into a dataframe, and remove columns from the dataframe

Answer (score 3):

Read the csv file one line at a time, and save just the parts you want in a new list of dictionaries.

```
with open('eggs.csv') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    mydata = [ {"CrimeDate": row["CrimeDate"], "Total Incidents": row["Total Incidents"]}
               for row in myreader ]
```

**Edit:** Since your real question was about summing up a column in groups, here's a nice way to do it. (I also edited your question so that it asks for what you actually want.)

This code uses `itertools.groupby` to group each set of records with the same date, then takes the sum of `TotalIncidents` for each group. It depends on records being sorted by date, so that the records for each sum appear together.

```
with open('eggs.csv') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    grouped_rows = itertools.groupby(myreader, lambda r: r["CrimeDate"])
    totals = list((date, sum(int(r["TotalIncidents"]) for r in grp) 
                  for date, grp in grouped_rows)

print(totals)
```

I'll leave it to you to convert the final list of dates and sums into a list of dictionaries, if that's really what you want.

Comment: It gives me TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: Oops, forgot a set of brackets, sorry! Fixed now

Comment: Actually Python 2.7 allows "dict literals". Much more readable now.

Comment: I think I got it, very helpful :)

Comment: I'm sorry my question was missunderstood, the output that I wanted was all the incidents summed up, this code is giving me only "CrimeDate" and "Total Incidents" but they are all separate, even the ones with the same date, I need that the incidents that happened in the same day, all get summed up.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very different question.  I don't have time to do a sum for you now, but it's just regular python programming. Try an explicit for-loop (not a comprehension) as you read line by line.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that.